# Reading a ResourceDictionary that contains special characters

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this example `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                    xml:space="preserve">

    <!--New line: &#x0d;-->    
    <s:String x:Key="Example.Line">New&#x0d;Line</s:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

If it's already in the project and I bind it to a control such as a `TextBlock` with `{DynamicBinding Example.Line}`, everything works as expected. (Both words in different lines)

Now, If I load that resource from a `.xaml` file by using `System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load()`, the special chars are replaced by `string.Empty`, like:

- `NewLine` instead of `New&#x0d;Line` or `New + Environment.NewLine + Line`.

This is how I load the resource:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    //I just realized that I could simply use the Source 
    //property without using the Load method. But the same thing happens.
    var dictionary = (ResourceDictionary)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(fs, new ParserContext { XmlSpace = "preserve" });
    dictionary.Source = new Uri(Path.GetFullPath(file), UriKind.Absolute);

    var test = dictionary["Example.Line"] as string;
 }
```

Is there any way to avoid the `XamlReader` from replacing the special characters codes?

---

### Working hack

By escaping the special chars with this code:

```
//Replaces the special chars.
var text = File.ReadAllText(file, Encoding.UTF8).Replace("&#", "&amp;#");
File.WriteAllText(file, text, Encoding.UTF8);

var dictionary = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri(Path.GetFullPath(file), UriKind.Absolute) };
```

I was able to load my `ResourceDictionary` without losing the new line values. Still, I don't believe this is the best way. :/

Answer (score 0):

you could use `ParserContext` parameter to XamlReader.Load :

```
XamlReader.Load(xaml, new ParserContext() { XmlSpace = "preserve" });
```

more at : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590393(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It still returns me strings without the special char.